# Issue in XAMPP controlling Apache shutdown

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, filezilla, ports

I get this error when I run Apache in XAMPP:

```
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: what exactly is your error? windows or mac or linux?

Comment: windows ...I run apache but its not run and this error occur

Comment: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: Turn off your internet connection and try again.

Comment: You installed 64 bit version or 32 bit version?